# EFCore 3.0 Devart Provider With OracleDB doen't work raw sql

Tags: c#, plsql, oracle11g, devart, ef-core-3.0

My project run on `.net core 3.1`, I use data provider `Devart.Oracle` also my project data stores on `OracleDB 11g`

My problem when i try to get sequence with EFCore V3.0 like that;

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
              _dbcontext.TABLEs.Add(values);
              var _sqlseq = string.Format(@"PACKAGE.MY_TABLE_SEQ");
              _dbcontext.TABLEs.FromSql(_sqlseq).FirstOrDefault();
              _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
              scope.Complete();
            }
```

Also I tried `FromSqlRaw` but i didn't take any result and idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my project packages like as below

EF Core 3.1.6
Devart 9.10.1054 versions then now i can run that query

```
var sql = string.Format(@"A TABLE QUERY");
 var result = _dbcontex.TABLESs.FromSqlRaw(sql).First();
```

Also i have another solition for run pure sql in .netcore projects

if you can use Dappet which is avalible for run pure sql framework like this,

```
var conn = this.GetConnection(_connectionString); // dapper connect DB with  connection string
        result = SqlMapper.Query<dynamic>(conn, query, null, commandType: CommandType.Text).First();
        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works successfully with EF Core v3.1 and dotConnect for Oracle v9.10.909:

```
var _sqlseq = string.Format(@"select * from dept");
var result = _dbcontext.DEPTs.FromSqlRaw(_sqlseq).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Specify the exact text of the error and its full stack trace.